# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED & TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, fetch-api

Have tried everything to connect my React frontend to my express backend (MongoDB). When I run nodemon server and go to URL "http://localhost:5000/api/projects/" I get full json list of data. When I fetch the same link in the frontend I get the errors: Failed to load resource:

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** & **TypeError: Failed to fetch.

I've seen this issue linked often but have tried the suggested solutions including checking CORS is enabled and the API link is correct. Neither have worked.

```
  fetch("https://localhost:5000/api/projects/", {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use axios : https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Then, to fetch from your API :

```
//declare a state
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])

axios.get('https://localhost:5000/api/projects/')
        .then(response => setProjects(response));
```

Comment: Did you add the "cors" package to your express app ?